# SQL Server Pass Query result to Variable in Store Procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to store a query result and store it in @Parameter, then I will like to use it in the INSERT query. I am new with SP and I dont know if I am doing this right or if its possible.

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[spTrans]
@Queue int,
@Parameter int = (SELECT TOP 1 TicketNumber + 1 from tblData WHERE QueueId = @Queue)
AS
BEGIN  
   INSERT INTO tblData (QueueId,Parameter) VALUES (@Queue,@Parameter)
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not move your sub query into your procedure like this:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[spTrans]
  @Queue int
AS
BEGIN  
  DECLARE @Parameter int 
  SELECT TOP 1 
    @Parameter = TicketNumber + 1 
  FROM tblData 
  WHERE QueueId = @Queue;

  INSERT INTO 
    tblData (QueueId,Parameter) 
  VALUES (@Queue,@Parameter);
END
```

If you need to optionally pass @Parameter in then do something like this:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[spTrans]
  @Queue int
, @Parameter int
AS
BEGIN  
  IF @Parameter = 0 
    SELECT TOP 1 
      @Parameter = TicketNumber + 1 
    FROM tblData 
    WHERE QueueId = @Queue;

  INSERT INTO 
    tblData (QueueId,Parameter) 
  VALUES (@Queue,@Parameter);
END
```